# calculating width and height from px to percent

Tags: css

I have the following css code:

```
body {
width: 80%; /* 1150px*/
margin:0 auto;
}

.icons {
float: right;
border: 1px black solid;
width:5.2173913%; /* 60/1150 */
height:60px;
margin:0 0.43478261%; /* 5/1150 */
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

If i try to convert the height to pixels as well - all the incons disappears.

I'm trying to make my webpage adaptive - so I need to convert my values to `%` and/or `em`, but is it really nessecary to convert the height?

Comment: If you're using `<img>` tags, and only set the width, the height will be automatically calculated.

Comment: You may be able to leave off the height or set `height:auto`. Can we see your HTML code?

Comment: @Kolink I add my images through CSS, using the background:url()

Comment: @showdev I add my images through CSS, so I don't think my HTML is very relevant

Comment: @Nilzone- You cannot size background images very easily if you are using pulling them in your css.  If you need to size images, I would suggest putting them into an `<img>` tag.  This has inherent properties that scale the image to whatever size you need easily.  All you have to do is scale either the width or height and it will keep the aspect ratio

Comment: use background-size for this. For example background-size:contain;

Comment: This might be helpful: http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios

Comment: @showdev that was such a good read. Thank you!